# Displaying a week calendar with blank fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a report outlining time slots for all 168 hours in a week for people to sign up.  The query below lists the basic data users have filled in but I'd like to see the slots that are also not signed up for.

Thanks in advance!

```
    SELECT
      p.[FirstName]
    , p.[LastName]
    , ( SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
        FROM [AttributeValue] av
        INNER JOIN [Attribute] a ON a.[Id] = av.[AttributeId] 
        AND a.[EntityTypeId] = 113 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierColumn] = 'WorkflowTypeId' 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierValue] = w.[WorkflowTypeId]
        WHERE [EntityId] = w.[Id] 
        AND a.[Key] = 'DayOfTheWeek'
      ) AS [Day]
    , (SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
        FROM [AttributeValue] av
        INNER JOIN [Attribute] a ON a.[Id] = av.[AttributeId] 
        AND a.[EntityTypeId] = 113 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierColumn] = 'WorkflowTypeId' 
        AND a.[EntityTypeQualifierValue] = w.[WorkflowTypeId]
        WHERE [EntityId] = w.[Id] 
        AND a.[Key] = 'Time'
      ) AS [Time]
FROM
[Workflow] w
INNER JOIN [PersonAlias] pa ON pa.Id = w.[InitiatorPersonAliasId]
INNER JOIN [Person] p ON p.[Id] = pa.[PersonId] 
WHERE w.[WorkflowTypeId] = 1032
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build all the hours between the dates in the week and then you can do a left join with your current query to get all the slots that are not used.

```
declare @startDate datetime ='2014-11-23'
declare @endDate  datetime ='2014-11-30'

;with cte
as
(
  your current query
)
, cte1
as
(
select datename(WEEKDAY, @startDate) as [day], datepart(hour, @startdate) as [time], 
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @startDate)+1, 0) as nextVal
union all
select datename(WEEKDAY, nextVal) as [day], datepart(hour, nextVal) as [time],
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, nextVal)+1, 0) as nextVal
from cte1
where nextVal<@endDate
)
select * from cte1
left join cte
on cte.day = cte1.day
and cte.time = cte1.time
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 168)
```

To get all slots not used alone, you can add where cte.day is NULL condition